# SQL how to implement if and else by checking column value

Tags: sql, ms-access

The table below contains customer reservations.  Customers come and make one record in this table, and the last day this table will be updated its `checkout_date` field by putting that current time.

**The Table**
[image: Reservations Table]

Now I need to extract all customers spending nights.

**The Query**

```
SELECT reservations.customerid, reservations.roomno, rooms.rate, 
reservations.checkin_date, reservations.billed_nights, reservations.status,
DateDiff("d",reservations.checkin_date,Date())+Abs(DateDiff("s",#12/30/1899
14:30:0#,Time())>0) AS Due_nights FROM reservations, rooms  WHERE
 reservations.roomno=rooms.roomno;
```

What I need is, if customer has checkout status, due nights will be calculated `checkin_date` subtracting by checkout date instead current date, also if customer has checkout date no need to add extra absolute value from `14:30`.

My current query view is below, also my computer time is `14:39` so it adds `1` to every query.

[image: current query Views]

Comment: Your query looks like MS Access, so I'm removing the extraneous database tags.

Comment: Ok thankz @GordonLinoff, i have added all predictions

Comment: @PaulF, can MS Access supports Switch Case. ?

Comment: As Access does not support `CASE` use an `IIF` instead. `DateDiff("d", checkin_date, IIF(status = 'checkout', checkout_date, Now()))`

Comment: @PaulFrancis: the question was tagged as MySQL when I looked at it originally, I see that tag has been removed.

Comment: @PaulFrancis, well done it works me thank you, put your comment as answer

Comment: @PaulF, I would use a CASE any day over a complicated IIF, if it were MSSQL. I did see the tag confusion too. However the table looked like Access, so I went with my intuition of IIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to calculate the Due nights upto the checkout date, and if they are still checked in use current date. I would suggest you to use an Immediate If.

The condition to check would be the `status` of the room. If it is `checkout`, then use the `checkout_date`, else use the `Now()`, something like.

```
SELECT 
    reservations.customerid, 
    reservations.roomno, 
    rooms.rate, 
    reservations.checkin_date, 
    reservations.billed_nights, 
    reservations.status,
    DateDiff("d", checkin_date, IIF(status = 'checkout', checkout_date, Now())) As DueNights
FROM 
    reservations 
    INNER JOIN      
    rooms  
    ON reservations.roomno = rooms.roomno;
```

As you might have noticed, I used a `JOIN`. This is more efficient than merging the two tables with common identifier. Hope this helps !